Should.ThrowAsync not catching exception from HttpClient.GetAsync() request
In our project we have a test written by a former colleague that is firing a request to an end point, which should - and does - return a 500 - InternalServerError (checking for this using Shouldly) after throwing an exception.
Code below simplified for demo purposes.
Endpoint:
[HttpGet]
[Route("machines/{idMachine:guid}/admin")]
[Authorize(Policy = Policies.RequireMachineCustomerCheck)]
public IActionResult MachineEditor(Guid idMachine)
{
    // Lookup machine...

    if (machine == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception");
    }
}

Test:
[Fact]
public async Task MachineNotFoundShouldThrowException()
{
    var idMachine = Guid.NewGuid();
    var uri = new Uri($"/machines/{idMachine}/admin", UriKind.Relative);
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}

However, since updating from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6, our Azure DevOps YAML deployment pipeline is reporting the exception when running the test. It is however being thrown from a different code path, in an Authorisation policy that we have on the end point:

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Exception: No machine could be found in the server's in-memory cache for a machine ID of
7f6825f9-3e4c-4d32-aace-ec9128394e0c. Either the cache is out-of-date
or the ID is incorrect.
at Proseal.Portal.Services.Utilities.CacheHelper.GetProVisionMachine(Guid
idMachine) in
D:\a\1\s\Proseal\Portal.Services\Utilities\CacheHelper.cs:line 72
at Proseal.Portal.Server.Common.Authorisation.MachineCustomerCheckHandler.HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext
context, MachineCustomerCheck requirement) in
D:\a\1\s\Proseal\Portal.Server\Common\Authorisation\MachineCustomerCheck.cs:line
83
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationHandler1.HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, Object resource, IEnumerable1 requirements)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy
policy, AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context,
Object resource)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
context)
at Proseal.Portal.Server.Common.Middleware.AuthenticationForStaticFilesMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext
context, RequestDelegate next) in
D:\a\1\s\Proseal\Portal.Server\Common\Middleware\AuthenticationForStaticFilesMiddleware.cs:line
43
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()

Auth policy registration:
public class Startup
{
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      services.AddAuthorization(options =>
      {
         options.AddPolicy(Policies.RequireMachineCustomerCheck, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MachineCustomerCheck()));
      }
   }
}

AuthHandler:
public class MachineCustomerCheckHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MachineCustomerCheck>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync()
    {
        // Lookup machine

        if (machine == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception");
        }
    }

Running the test locally in Visual Studio 2022's Test Explorer is not throwing an exception or failing, but debugging it confirms the exception is thrown. Due to the 500 being returned as a result of that, the test is still passing. Not sure why the deployment pipeline is behaving differently to VS.
Wrapping the test in a try-catch was my first thought, but the exception is not being caught.
try
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    exception.Message.ShouldBe("Exception");
}

After some googling I altered this, but got the same behaviour.
try
{
    await Task.Run(async () => await httpClient.GetAsync(uri));
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    exception.Message.ShouldBe("Exception");
}

I've also tried using Shouldly's ShouldThrowAsync method: https://docs.shouldly.org/documentation/exceptions/throw#shouldthrowasync, but this is also failing to catch the exception.
Func<Task> func = async () => await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

await Should.ThrowAsync<Exception>(func);

Concerned there may be another issue at foot with the async code (and therefore the exception) being contained in a separate thread, but my async knowledge isn't the best and so I'm coming up short on other things to try.

Please post the stack trace of the exception that you get in the pipeline.

Apologies, edited my question with more context around the pipeline exception.

So firstly on an unelated issue, your auth handler shouldnt throw an exception in the case that no requested data was found. You end up telling potential attackers more info than a regular user needs. Either the auth handle has succeeded or its failed and the user gets 401. If you get 500 in the case of data not found, the attacker can brute force the end point to figure out what machines exist.

Secondly, something doesnt seem quite right with what you have posted. The test runner caught an exception with the AuthorizationHandler but the test that you have posted uses a HttpClient to make the call. The test runner would not have a stacktrace of the the ASP middleware if it were being called via an endpoint.

TLDR; from what I can see in the information you have posted, the application code is throwing an uncaught exception, not the test. If that's confirmed to be the case, you probably want to check what you have configured for your ASP error handling as it seems the exception in he AuthorizationHandler isnt being passed down the middleware chain. Like I said, you're better off removing the exception anyway.

The code to lookup a machine (in the CacheHelper from the stack trace) is used in a lot of places in the solution, so there has just been some code re-use which sounds like it might be incorrect.
The HttpClient is the property of a InMemoryWebHostWithSqlServerFixture class that we have, in which the HttpClient is constructed from a derivative of a WebApplicationFactory, using the .CreateClient() method.
I can certainly look at removing the exception and handling it differently.

Acting on your "your auth handler shouldnt throw an exception in the case that no requested data was found" comment, I have edited the auth handler to catch the exception and instead return a 401. This has then highlighted that the tests weren't structured correctly, or even testing the correct thing in one instance. Thanks very much for assisting!

Glad I could assist. You could post an answer to your own question, detailing what you did to resolve your problem, and then mark it as the solution to close this question.

To fix this, I've stopped the auth handler from throwing an exception, by catching the exception and returning a 401 instead. This then allows the tests to correctly check the auth handler behaviour.
These changes have also highlighted some issues with the way our tests have been structured, and so re-working them has now solved my problems.

If you use XUnit for example, you can expect an exception like this:
 await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ExceptionType>(() => testContext.httpClient.GetAsync(uri));

If you continue to get an exception that doesn't fall into this category, check your DI. Have run into scenarios in the past where there was a DI error that was not caught/ thrown correctly.
